# How to use Jquery autocomplete plugin for Django in this view?

Tags: jquery, django

I am using the geonode in Django and want to include jquery in this . I am following this tutorial http://solutions.treypiepmeier.com/2009/12/10/using-jquery-autocomplete-with-django/ .

The problem is I am not able to understand in which form object should I write the charfield?

And are there are any better code snippets forit?

Answer (score 0):

That tutorial assumes you are building your HTML forms using "Django forms".

Read the [Django forms docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) to learn how to use them.

In this case the `forms.TextInput` you see in the tutorial means that Django will generate an HTML element of `<input type="text" />`. If you are more concerned with just learning about making jQuery Autocomplete work, then you can just hardcode the `<input type="text" />` element yourself into your template file.